# Can I collapse foreach, using and other c# code blocks in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Can I collapse foreach, using and other c# code blocks in Visual Studio 2010, the same way that I can collapse methods, properties, classes, namespaces, etc? It would be very helpful sometimes.

Comment: `Can I` or `How can I`? First - you can't. Second - see blow (and edit your question please)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `#region #endregion` directives to create collapsible areas.

**Update**:

By the way, why do you need this functionality? There's a good principle to keep your methods as short as possible (Uncle Bob calls it `extract until you drop`). If you stick to it you won't need additional collapsible areas.

Comment: Good for short term, but I wouldn't want to leave them in the code. Thanks.

Comment: A've added one more thought I got

Comment: I adhere to those principles, but sometimes there are atomic units of code that just run long and can't be or don't deserve to be broken down: when calling methods in an external API that has LOTS of parameters; when the chance of needing to reuse code is zero.

Comment: Regions are helpful in that they collapse  code, but they can also cause compile errors, which bugs me.  The compiler should not care that there is no #endregion.  But that aside, I find that the ability to collapse foreach loops would be very handy, and use it all the time in NotePad++ and SciTE.  Code that logically belongs together should stay together - not be refactored overmuch.

Answer (score 1):

Cut + paste the code out of the foreach loop and into a function, collapse the function away?

E.g.,

```
public void MyMessyFunction()
{
  // ...

  foreach(string foo in bar)
  {
    // Do ugly stuff
  }

  // ...
}
```

Turns into

```
public void MyMessyFunction()
{
  // ...

  foreach(string foo in bar)
  {
    DoUglyStuff(foo, bar);
  }

  // ...
}

#region Stuff I want to hide

public void DoUglyStuff(string foo, List<string> bar)
{
  // Do ugly stuff
}

#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, you can collapse an arbitrary region in Visual Studio 2010. Try selecting a region, then press Ctrl+M twice (assuming C# key bindings).

In VS2008, this is found under Edit -> Outlining; I don't have a 2010 installed so can't try it out there readily.

**Edit:** Actually, it looks like VS2008 has something similar in its "Hide Selection" feature (found in the same place), but it appears to only be available in some languages.